# How to make flexbox boxes choosable?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, flexbox

I have a flexbox row with boxes that looks like this.

[image]

How to make it as options? So when you click on one of them, you check checkbox and the chosen box is highlighted.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s84tw4k9/)

```
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #C3D0D9;
  border: 1px solid #C3D0D9;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You want to make them checkboxes or clickable options only?
As soon as, you will click... you can add a correct icon on the box and change background-color of box so that it looks like it has been selected.

Comment: easiest way would be to add jQuery and create some click events that target the checkboxes that are hidden if you are really needing form type elements otherwise you can just toggle a class that has a border or whatever in it. I can showan example if you want

Comment: @Nitesh l need to know an option chosen among these boxes. Visually you described it right.

Comment: @happymacarts I would be happy to see the approach without JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery
I added data-id attributes which are not needed for this feature but can be useful if you need to capture that later or if the elements are generated from your db

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flex-item').on('click', function() {
    //console.log($(this).data('id'));
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    /*if(!$('#check_'+$(this).data('id')+':checked')){
        $('#check_'+$(this).data('id')).prop('checked', true);
    }else {
    $('#check_'+$(this).data('id')).prop('checked', false);
    }*/
    var checkBox = $('#check_' + $(this).data('id'));
    checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));

  })

})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #C3D0D9;
  border: 1px solid #C3D0D9;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#hidden_form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item" data-id="1">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item" data-id="2">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item" data-id="3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item" data-id="4">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item" data-id="5">5</li>
</ul>
<form id="hidden_form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check_1" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check_2" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check_3" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check_4" value="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check_5" value="5" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping in mind the further interaction with database! Nice answer!

Comment: Do you plan to submit the selection?

Comment: Yes, I intend to do this.

Comment: i modified the answer to include the relevant form as well